# open problem in numerical analysis

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, stability

I am interested in open and current issues in numerical analysis, there are good references in this respect. Thanks for your response

Comment: this is very broad; the site works best if you can bring a focus to your question.

Comment: I agree with @CarloBeenakker: the question is very interesting but it is too broad. You should try to focus on some of the subfields of numerical analysis: perhaps it is a good idea to put emphasis on what could be or could became your specific interest. Are you interested in
* Interpolation of functions
* Numerical evaluation of integrals
* Numerical methods for solving functional equations (finite differences, finite element et similia)
* Computer mathematics (radix algorithms, algorithms for the calculation of floating points / binary numbers and the like)
* and so on?